# Inequality involving $n$-degree polynomials and $\sup$s

Tags: polynomials, inequalities

I started by asking in MSE the following problem: consider
$$
\Theta:(\Bbb R[X],||\cdot||_{\lambda})\longrightarrow(\mathcal C^{\lambda}[0,1],||\cdot||_{\lambda})
$$
defined as 
$$
\Theta(p):=\sup_{u\le\cdot}p(u)
$$
where $||\cdot||_{\lambda}$ denotes the usual $\lambda-$Holder norm, with $0<\lambda\le1$, i.e.
$$
||f||_{\lambda}:=||f||_{\infty}+\sup_{0\le s<t\le1}\frac{|f(t)-f(s)|}{|s-t|^{\lambda}}
$$
and $\mathcal C^{\lambda}[0,1]:=\{f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R\;:\;||f||_{\lambda}<+\infty\}$.

Is $\Theta$ a Lipschitz operator? Is there a way to prove/disprove my statement?

If $\Theta$ were linear it would suffice to show the lipschitzianity near the zero polynomial; but $\Theta$ is *sublinear*: what can be said about these operators?

For this it suffices to show the following
$$
\max_{t\in[0,1]}\left|\sup_{u\le t}p(u)-\sup_{u\le t}q(u)\right|\le
C_1\max_{t\in[0,1]}\left|p(t)-q(t)\right|\\
\left|\sup_{u\le t}p(u)-\sup_{u\le t}q(u)-\sup_{u\le s}p(u)+\sup_{u\le s}q(u)\right|\le C_2\left|p(t)-q(t)-p(s)+q(s)\right|
$$
for every $p,q\in\Bbb R[X]$ and for all $0\le s<t\le1$; but this point I thought MO was more appropriated for this new problem.

Many thanks for any hint!